# xpath for div content when hovers over a <li>

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, xpath, expand

I am new to web **scraping** and xpath and thought the best way to learn is to try **scraping** a real website.
Here is an example of website I want to scrape.
https://www.thebump.com/b/most-popular-baby-names

My aim is to get a list of 100 popular baby names and also information about the names. For example, Name number 1 is Mila, Gender is Girl, Style is Modern, Popularity is 60 as shown in the screenshot below.

[Screenshot showing the information i want to scrape when i put my cursor over the name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l95tv.png)

I inspect the HTML code and realise that when I put my cursor over the any name in the table, say Mila, the (li) and (a href) class will change and have a word "expand" in them. However, it is unclear to me which div actually contains the data I want (the box which shows up after I hover over the (li)). How would you approach this problem?

Edited: I have solved the problem and am posting my code here.

```
url='https://tb-babynames-api.thebump.com/v2/lists/most-popular-baby-names?order=asc&sortBy=popularity&limit=1000'

page = requests.get(url)

parsed = json.loads(page.content)
nameList = parsed['items']

for n in nameList:
    print (nameList)
```

Comment: Instead of adding text can you add specific code where you are stuck?

Comment: Thank you Chirag. Sorry i didn't manage to get back to you over the past few days. I have examined the website again and manage to follow the ajax request and get what I want. I will post my code up here.